# Is Voat.co affiliated with Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

[Voat.co](http://voat.co), an alternative to [Reddit.com](http://reddit.com) is very similar to Stack Exchange in design. This could be due to the fact that both use the same "forum template" (for lack of a better term), but I always imagined Stack Exchange to be original considering all the developers on the team.

On Voat I have noticed these similarities in the formatting:

- Italic text: `*text*`
- Bold text: `**text**`
- Link with description: `[description](URL)`
- Code: `` `code` ``
- Code block: `[four spaces]code`
- Quotes: `> Quote`

Furthermore, every subverse (equivalent to Reddit's subreddit) has its own design that differs slightly from the others - just like the different Stack Exchange communities.

Have they perhaps copied the design from SE?

Comment: I've only read about Voat with respect to various events on Reddit, but in terms of moderation and policy the site couldn't be more different from SE. I'm pretty sure that SE has nothing to do with Voat. The formatting you mention is Markdown, which is semi-standardized

Comment: (1) Note that Reddit itself also uses Markdown. To show backticks inside an inline code block, use an extra bactick on each side to delimit the block, plus a space to separate formatting backticks from content backticks if necessary. See the edit to your question for an example (I would demonstrate it in this comment instead, but for some reason this escaping doesn't seem to work in it.)

Comment: @duplode you can backslash escape backticks in comments (i.e `\\``)

Comment: @Cai Now that you mention it, that might have been good enough for my purposes (i.e. \`\` \`code\` \`\`). By the way, it is worth mentioning the proper markup doesn't work because of the ["mini-markdown" restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: No, that's just a straight-up Reddit clone. Both Reddit and Stack Exchange use Markdown for post formatting (the source of all the italic, bold, link etc formatting syntax you quoted), so it makes sense that this thing would to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The similar things are:

- Voting: Stack Exchange does not hold a patent for the voting idea, it existed long before Stack Overflow was created, and many sites use this.
- Formatting: as [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/is-voat-co-affiliated-with-stack-exchange#comment933336_287623) and [Pops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/is-voat-co-affiliated-with-stack-exchange#comment933338_287624) mention in their comments, this is something called Markdown, which is standard and very common. As [its official website](http://commonmark.org/) says:

  > ### What is Markdown?
  >
  > It’s a plain text format for writing structured documents, based on formatting conventions from email and usenet.

So to sum this up: Voat.co is not affiliated in any way with Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is the formatting syntax used on SE standardized somehow? How come they are the same?

Comment: The formatting system is called Markdown, and it is not specific to Stack Exchange. It's got [a Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [an open standard effort](http://commonmark.org/) if you're interested in that part specifically.

Comment: @Gendarme you also got a [comment on your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/is-voat-co-affiliated-with-stack-exchange/287624?noredirect=1#comment933336_287623), explaining this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, he just edited the comment to add it. Alright, I got it.